# JavaScript: Code says "cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" but I can't fix the problem

Tags: javascript, typeerror, indexof

The code is used in a HTML document, where when you press a button the first word in every sentence gets marked in **bold**

This is my code:

```
var i = 0; 
while(i < restOftext.length) {
    if (text[i] === ".") {
        var space = text.indexOf(" ", i + 2);
        var tekststykke = text.slice(i + 2, space);
        var text = text.slice(0, i) + "<b>" + tekststykke + "</b>" + text.slice(i + (tekststykke.length + 2));
        var period = text.replace(/<b>/g, ". <b>");
        var text2 = "<b>" + firstWord + "</b>" + period.slice(space1);

        i++
    }
}
document.getElementById("firstWordBold").innerHTML = text2;
```

}

```
It's in the first part of the code under function firstWordBold(); where it says there is an error with
    var space1 = text.indexOf(" ");
```

Comment: Where are you calling `firstWordBold(text)`?

Comment: he's not, he is calling `Svovlstikkerne` and expecting it to know what text is.

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: @JDunken If it throws an error at `text.indexOf(" ")`, then it needs to be called from somewhere. Apparently from a onclick event of a button. But I'd like to see how that is called.

Comment: @Ivar this is the button:
 `<p id="text2"></p>
 <button type="button" onclick="firstWordBold()">Tryk her</button>`

Comment: @Olivia `firstWordBold` expects a `text` parameter. You are not passing any.

Comment: @Ivar I have tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Olivia You have declared the variable `text` at the top of your example. If you are not shadowing it, it should be able to find it. Please provide a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the problem ourselves. Without it, we can't help you.

Comment: @Olivia Actually I think adding `text = document.getElementById('firstWordBold').textContent;` as a first line in the "firstWorldBold" function will most probably solve what you are trying to do, right?

Comment: `text` is `undefined` inside the function scope because it is one of the arguments of the function (because it is in the brackets behind the function name). That is why JavaScript is looking for the variable `text` **inside the scope of the function**. Unless you pass any value into the function (as mentioned by @Ivar) `text` does not have any value inside the function and thus is `undefined`. Actually, it would also be a solution to simply use `function firstWordBold(){...`. In this case JavaScript will look for (and find) `text` **outside** the function scope.

Comment: @sborn will it work if I make a new function for the text piece inside the `function firstWordBold()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing quote on your string, at least in the example you provided in the question.

Your problem is the scope of the `text` variable. In `firstWordBold` change every `text` to `this.text`, except the last two where you re-define `text`

Also, if you want to apply bold to the first word this is easier...

```
document.getElementById('test-div-2').innerHTML = '<b>' + firstWord + '</b>' + restOftext;
```

It now works for me, with no errors and it applies bold to the first word.

Here's how the function ended up,

```
function firstWordBold() {
        console.log('bolding!');
        var space1 = this.text.indexOf(' ');
        var firstWord = this.text.slice(0, space1);
        var restOftext = this.text.slice(space1);

        document.getElementById('test-div-2').innerHTML = '<b>' + firstWord + '</b>' + restOftext;
      }
```

To make every first word bold, try this...

```
function firstWordBold() {
        let newHTML = '';

        const sentences = this.text.split('.');
        for (let sentence of sentences) {
          sentence = sentence.trim();
          var space1 = sentence.indexOf(' ');
          var firstWord = sentence.slice(0, space1);
          var restOftext = sentence.slice(space1);
          newHTML += '<b>' + firstWord + '</b>' + restOftext + ' ';
        }

        document.getElementById('test-div-2').innerHTML = newHTML;
      }
```

One last edit, I didn't notice you had sentences ending with anything other that a period before. To split on multiple delimiters use a regex, like so,

```
const sentences = this.text.split(/(?<=[.?!])\s/);
```

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake. I cut my string shorter because it's very long. But it is closed in my code-document

Comment: closing that string eliminates any js errors, but is not applying `bold` to the first word.

Comment: But when I run the code with the string closed it still comes up with that error. What do you mean by "is not applying bold to the first word"?

Comment: I've changed every `text` to `this.text` in `firstWordBold` and I think it fixed it, but now when I try to click the button it won't show the text with the first word bold.

Comment: OMG it worked! But I have to have it in a loop so that It makes the first word of every sentence **bold**

Comment: Oh, I thought only the first word needed to be in bold. Updated my answer again :)

Comment: Still has a bug where it's replacing all the sentence ends with a period regardless of what was there before, but it's 90% there now.

Comment: Sure thing, how 'bout marking my answer as the answer ;)

Comment: Alright, I couldn't stand it, I fixed the bug with a different regex.